# Run the same macros in two workbooks

Tags: macros

I would like to run this same code in two workbooks. The code puts data labels on an xy scatter chart. Here is the code:

```
Sub AttachLabelsToPoints()

   'Dimension variables.
   Dim Counter As Integer, ChartName As String, xVals As String

   ' Disable screen updating while the subroutine is run.
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'Store the formula for the first series in "xVals".
   xVals = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula

   'Extract the range for the data from xVals.
   xVals = Mid(xVals, InStr(InStr(xVals, ","), xVals, _
      Mid(Left(xVals, InStr(xVals, "!") - 1), 9)))
   xVals = Left(xVals, InStr(InStr(xVals, "!"), xVals, ",") - 1)
   Do While Left(xVals, 1) = ","
      xVals = Mid(xVals, 2)
   Loop

   'Attach a label to each data point in the chart.
   For Counter = 1 To Range(xVals).Cells.Count
     ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).HasDataLabel = _
         True
      ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).DataLabel.Text = _
         Range(xVals).Cells(Counter, 1).Offset(0, -1).Value
   Next Counter

End Sub
```

Is there is any way to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question needs clarification. Is there something wrong with the code? You say you want to run it on two workbooks, then ask if there is a way to fix it. That is two different things. What have you tried or researched to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Save this code in a VSTO addin (xla or xlax) and add a reference to it in as many workbooks as you want. Please refer the following to learn about VSTO (Excel add-in): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx